# New version of these javascript files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am wondering these files get generated when you make an asp.net mvc 3 file.

```
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

I am wondering do they update these only on new releases of mvc or are they regularly updating these versions?

Same with the asp.net mvc templates. When I make a new project I still get like jquery version 1.4.4.

Anyway to update these templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a new project and then the first thing you can go is go to the nuget package manager and update all the installed packages. This will allow you to update jquery and other packages to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than waiting for updates, you can easily [create your own project template](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx) instead of using the one provided for you.

Comment: Ya that would probably work but I am most interested in the 2 files I listed as those are something I cannot update myself